# Is there always a vector $x$ with positive entries such that $Ax=b$ for $b$ positive $A$ positive definite?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a positive definite $n\times n$ matrix $A$, does there exist an $n \times 1$ vector $x$ with all entries positive such that the vector $Ax=b$ has all entries positive ?

I think there is a counter example.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Question edited, sorry.

Comment: Can we assume that $A$ is a _real_ matrix (which is positive definite)?

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is positive definite then it is non-singular and you can compute its inverse. Hence,

$$x=A^{-1}b$$

**EDIT:** (in response to your updated question)

If I understand you correctly, both is possible. E.g.

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}10&-5\\-5&10\end{array}\right),\quad x=(4\quad 1)^T\\
Ax=\left(\begin{array}{c}35\\-10\end{array}\right)$$

And with

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}10&5\\5&10\end{array}\right),\quad x=(4\quad 1)^T\\
Ax=\left(\begin{array}{c}45\\30\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: Oooops sorry, I edited the question.